# Macro stopped to compile on Linux

Tags: c++, macros, g++, xlc

I have a library with several macros, it compiles fine on AIX, but now i need to compile the same code and it seems the macros stopped to work.
I keep receiving the message:

```
error: pasting "::" and "EVENT_DATA" does not give a valid preprocessing token.
```

Is there a way to make the c++ preprocessor on linux acts like on aix.
I'm using g++ on linux and xlc_r on AIX.

Here is one of the macros.

```
#define E_TRA_INMOD(MName, Comp) \
   static const ES_TracMg::ES_TracComps ES_TracComp = \
                                    ES_TracMg::##Comp; \
   static char* ES_Mod_Namp = MName; \
   static unsigned long ES_SerMas = \
               ES_TracMg::m_MServ[ES_TracMg##Comp];
```

I call it like `E_TRA_INMOD("Error", EVENT_DATA);`
The error is:

```
error: pasting "::" and "EVENT_DATA" does not give a valid preprocessing token.
```

Comment: What is the error message? Or what is it you are getting and you don't like?

Comment: The error message is: error: pasting "::" and "EVENT_DATA" does not give a valid preprocessing token.

Comment: you can use `cpp` programm to see your sources after preprocessing

Comment: @user286215, not if `cpp` refuses to preprocess it!

Comment: The error message does not seem to relate to the use that you point to, where is `EVENT_DATA` in your code?

Comment: Sorry, i have several error messages, so i copied one of them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you don't want to use `##` here:

```
#define E_TRA_INMOD(MName, Comp) \
   static const ES_TracMg::ES_TracComps ES_TracComp = \
                                    ES_TracMg::##Comp; \
```

It should be

```
#define E_TRA_INMOD(MName, Comp) \
   static const ES_TracMg::ES_TracComps ES_TracComp = \
                                    ES_TracMg::Comp; \
```

You don't have two tokens to glue together into a single token, you just have whatever `Comp` expands to.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do in the macro?  It looks like the first token paste is redundant:

```
#define E_TRA_INMOD(MName,Comp) \
   static const ES_TracMg::ES_TracComps ES_TracComp = \
                                    ES_TracMg::Comp; \
   static char* ES_Mod_Namp = MName; \
   static unsigned long ES_SerMas = \
               ES_TracMg::m_MServ[ES_TracMg##Comp];
```